# Avoiding jQuery conflicts when widget instantiates its own jQuery dependency?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refactoring code for an HTML widget (the social icons type) in which the original developer wrote the widget applicaton as a jQuery extension. The widget is called as shown below and uses $.noConflict() but pages that have jQuery already instantiated are having conflicts with the jQuery called by the widget.

Is there any workaround to having jQuery called twice? On some pages it appears to be overwriting other jQuery extensions added prior to the widget's  tag, see it's source below. The actual widget is another file, this is the init code that's loaded from the  tag and which is causing the jQuery conflict.

```
    var xRemote = 'http://assets.xxxx.com/webwidget/',
    jquerySrc = xRemote + 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';

    var appStart = function () {

        // callback loader
        var callback = function () {
            $.getScript(xRemote + "app/easyXDM/easyXDM.min.js", function (data, status, jqxhr) {
                $.getScript(xRemote + "lib/jquery/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js", function (data, status, jqxhr) {
                    $.getScript(xRemote + "app/public/js/jsonlite.js", function (data, status, jqxhr) {
                        $.getScript(xRemote + "app/public/js/xxx.js", function (data, status, jqxhr) {
                            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                            $j('body').xxxxxwidgetextension();
                            $j('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />');
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        createStyleLink();
        loadjQuery(jquerySrc, callback);

    }

    // create link to stylesheet
    function createStyleLink() {

        var ss = document.createElement("link");
        ss.type = "text/css";
        ss.rel = "stylesheet";
        ss.href = xRemote + "app/public/css/xxxwidget.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);

    }

    // load jQuery with callback
    function loadjQuery(url, callback) {

        // create <script> tag
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = url;
        if (s.addEventListener) {
            s.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
        }
        else if (s.readyState) {
            s.onreadystatechange = callback;
        }
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }

    appStart();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check whether jQuery is already loaded?

```
if(jQuery == undefined){
    loadjQuery(jquerySrc, callback);
} else {
    callback();
}
```

Comment: We thought of this. In this case we would be making a crap shoot since there are so many different versions of jQuery.. depending on the site owner's version could potentially break some of the jQuery functionality in our main app.